# Copy jQAssistant scan results to another Neo4J Server

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant

Our daily builds use jQAssistant to scan and analyze our projects.
We have a server already running Neo4J and i would like to move the jQA results to this server to explore the project later on.

The jqassistant folder, which is generated during the build, contains:

```
- jqassistant
-- logs [subfolder]
-- report [subfolder]
-- rules [subfolder]
-- store [subfolder]
-- jqassistant-report.xml
-- store_lock
```

Sadly, I have the following restrictions:

- The build server and the one running Neo4J cannot communicate directly, so a [JQAssistant Team Server](https://101.jqassistant.org/setting-up-a-team-server/index.html) is not possible.
- The server running Neo4J is not supposed to have Java and Maven installed, otherwise we could just copy the resulting jqassistant folder and start the embedded Neo4J server using jQA

Is there a way to copy the jqassistant folder and direct Neo4J to it and have it read as a dbms? 
If not, is it possible to create a Neo4J ready dbms from jQA?

Answer (score 0):

The jQA "store" directory is a folder managed by Neo4j and thus can be copied to another Neo4j instance (or used by it).